# Objects detection in OpenCv without haarcascades

Tags: python, opencv

1. I want to detect my own objects, which arent in any classifier. For example: fly. Color extraction isnt useful because fly is very small and black and it has the same color as backgroung on some pictures. I wanted to use ORB and SIFT, but it gave me few matches.

How i can do this?

2. Where i can find any friendly documentation about OpenCv? I cant understand how i should use official documentation. In which modules should i search for my methods and classes?

And when i made my app with official documentation's examples, some methods had another arguments. Not like in documentation. But my opencv version is the newest

P.S. Sorry for my English, i'm Russian

Answer (score 0):

You can use opencv `dnn` module `readNetFrom...` functions to load various pretrained model formats such as `onnx`,
tensorflow `pb`, `caffe`, darknet `weights` etc. These can be used for inference and you may need to do some post processing to get final object bounding boxes.

For training custom object detection model to use in opencv this can be good start,

https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

Opencv dnn samples and tutorial,

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d58/tutorial_table_of_content_dnn.html

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/dnn

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html